# How to make php aritsan tinker to print latest output?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan, iterm2, tinker

im running script trought the php artisan tinker and i faced this problem:
when my loop is printing something to console, when reaches terminal height, it stops printing. Then, when it finished, terminal prints last message which is done with dd command.
To see other stuff(after printing stopped) i have to press any button to scroll down and see latest printed messages. Im not sure what causes the problem, but as i remember in the past it was always printing latest actual output. Any clues?

Comment: the dd command might be an issue since it 'dies'. Do you get a tinker prompt after that point? If so using `$_` might work. It's built on top of psysh which has a few additional useful features: https://github.com/bobthecow/psysh/wiki/Magic-variables

Comment: Hey thanks for replay. Actually it doesn't matter, i can write simple loop directly to console, for example `for($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {echo uniqid();} echo "done";` and it's the same result, it stops printing when it reaches bottom of terminal, so i have press enter or any other key to reach latest "echos"

Comment: Btw i noticed that terminal name changes to php (more)

Comment: Looks like it might depend what terminal you are using.  No problems here.

Comment: I'm using iTerm2, tryed native MacOS terminal, but result is the same

Comment: what shell do you use?

Comment: Im using Zsh shell

Comment: working fine in VScode, and in windows terminal.  On OSX with iterm2, the output seems to go into a 'more' like interface, requiring space to step between screens of output, and Q to quit

Comment: Ok i found solution! I had to create config.php file for psysh and add setting `pager' => false`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.